# Can the Cython's pyx file take only a small part of the header's defenitions

Tags: python, c++, cython

Say we have a c++ class defined in a header file which has many different functions and attributes but we only need to access only one of its functions on the python side.

Does this make the Cython implementation easier(can we only define the relevant small part of the header file in the pyx/pyd) ?

In addition, is there any other tool better than Cython in such case, where having low latency is also important?

Comment: Short answer: yes - you can and should just wrap the bits you need

Comment: Thanks @DavidW , it would be greatly user friendly then:)